# Is eating rice everyday healthy?

Tags: diet, weight-loss, calories, carbohydrate

I am trying to lose lbs and I was told that if I eat rice I will feel fuller faster. So is this true? Is it healthy to eat rice everyday? Are some kinds or rice really better than others? Are there a lot of calories or carbs in rice?

Note that I and using a rice cooker. Does this matter too?

Comment: I can't give a detailed answer, but I will say that brown rice is healthier than white rice due to its fiber content.  Many brown rices are bland though, and I'd recommend brown basmati for its flavor.

Comment: @SteveWortham Brown rice has been perceived as healthier than white rice. Much of it is generally not broken down by our bodies and is [torture on our gut](http://www.thehealthyhomeeconomist.com/what-white-rice-better-than-brown/).

Comment: Rice doesn't have a lot of nutritional value, but as a grain white rice is least damaging to your body.  It's macronutrient makeup is primarily carbohydrates.  http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/cereal-grains-and-pasta/5712/2

Comment: This question has no relation to exercise and is therefore off-topic [as you can read in our FAQ](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/faq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really hard to answer your question because it depends what rice is replacing in your diet. I wouldn't necessary say it's the healthiest possible choice to eat rice every day. It's *healthier* than eating french fries every day, but probably not as healthy as eating steamed broccoli every day.

If you *are* going to eat rice every day, I don't think brown rice has much if any health advantage over white--it may even be worse as some of the commenters have mentioned. In general, rice is a high-carb food. Compared with other high-carb foods, it may not be the healthiest choice. I would rate sweet potatoes or even white potatoes healthier, as long as they are boiled or steamed, because they are less likely to [spike your blood sugar](http://www.mendosa.com/gilists.htm) and they [fill you up more](http://www.mendosa.com/satiety.htm). They also have more vitamins and minerals per calorie.

But in general, it's better to think of your diet as a whole rather than specific foods. For example, my potato theory goes out the window if you melt a half stick of butter on it or fry it. If you want a healthy diet, start by eating lots of vegetables. If some of them are raw, or at least not fried in oil, all the better. Other healthy foods include legumes (lentils, chickpeas, kidney beans), fruit, nuts and seeds (especially hazelnuts and almonds), fish (especially wild salmon or tilapia) and lean poultry, and extra virgin olive oil. If you are eating a good amount of these other foods, there is certainly room for some higher-carb foods (potatoes, rice, etc.), but I wouldn't make them the base of your food pyramid.

Answer (score 2):

This is just from personal experience. I get that "full feeling", from fat and proteins. If I eat a high-fat breakfast, I stay full 5-6 hours. Otherwise, that time is about half.